# Application Error - net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am trying to build and run my Meteor app on Android. If I simply run

```
meteor run android-device
```

or

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://<host>
```

It loads up on my device (LG-E988, Android version 4.4.2).

However, when I build the app into a `.apk` and run it on my device, it would not start. Here're my steps:

---

I have already added the platforms, added `mobile-config.js` etc. Here are my last steps:

1. Navigate into my project's directory and run:

   ```
   $ meteor build ~/Desktop/project-build/ --server=http://<host>:<port> --verbose
   ```

   I get a success message.

   ```
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL

   Total time: 2 mins 37.466 secs
   Built the following apk(s): Android
   ```
2. Navigate to `~/Desktop/project-build/android/` and I find a `project/` directory, a `README` and a `release-unsigned.apk`.

   I then signed the `release-unsigned.apk`:

   ```
   $ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /home/dayuloli/.keystore release-unsigned.apk <alias>
   ```

   Then I verified that it has been signed:

   ```
   $ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs release-unsigned.apk
   ```

   And the console printed `jar verified.`.
3. Next I `zipalign`

   ```
   $ $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/23.0.2/zipalign 4 release-unsigned.apk production.apk
   ```
4. Sends the `production.apk` to my Android device. When I ran the app, I get an **Application Error** with the following message:

   ```
   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
   ```

---

Observations

1. The app icon shows the cordova logo instead of the logo icons I specified in the `mobile-config.js`
2. When I unpacked the `production.apk`, I don't see a `android_asset` directory. But I do see a `assets/www/` directory, but this has no `index.html` in it.

---

How can I resolve this issue?